# Ommitting a specific pattern from a regex statement

Tags: php, regex

I've spent the last couple of days trying to figure out how to resolve this particular issue and posting on SO, but no dice so far.  I think this is probably easier than I've been making it to be, but I need some help;

Here is a pretty basic regex statement that linkifies pretty much any link.  It's not the only regex pattern I have, so I've included a piece that skips over the link if it includes the specific pattern "img.youtube.com/vi/"  It works great;

```
$message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)?!(img.youtube.com/vi/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,])+#i", "<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>", $message);
```

I do not want this to linkify any url with .jpeg, jpg, gif, or any popular image format, I have another expression that will embed those kinds of links (and it works fine, too).  So, I need to find a way to get this expression to reject those kinds of links.

I've gotten advice on negative lookarounds, matching to specific strings, but none of them seem to work so far.  I need to find a way to get this regex to ignore any URL that ends with .jpeg and so forth;

So, the regex statement above already has an example of a string that disqualifies certain URLs - ?!(img.youtube.com/vi/).  This seems like that's all I need to do, but where do I put it and how does it look?  The + symbol in the statement makes it so that the regex will scrutinize the string all the way to the end of it, using the matching characters of [-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=,].  So, this matching string should probably be put somewhere before the + symbol.  Does it go in "?!(img.youtube.com/vi/)"  ?  In my mind, it should probably look like this;

```
$message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)?!(img.youtube.com/vi/|/^\.jpeg$/|/^\.jpg$/|/^\gif$/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,])+#i", 
"<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>", $message);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @kikomaru Now there is online demo in my answer http://ideone.com/419yfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer and also clean up your regexp

```
(?i)((?:f|ht)tps?://((?!img|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp))(?:([-a-z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&;/=,])(?2))+(?!(?3)))
```

Now the `img` etc you don't want is in the neg lookahead and you can add a things you don't like.

```
$good="http://www.google.com/";
$bad="http://img.google.com/";
$r="#(?i)((?:f|ht)tps?://((?!img|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp))(?:([-a-z0-9()@:%_+.~\#?&;/=,])(?2))+(?!(?3)))#";
$rep="<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>"; 
echo preg_replace($r,$rep,$good); 
echo preg_replace($r,$rep,$bad);
```

You can try here http://ideone.com/419yfm

Comment: Thank you, Hans - this totally works.  I appreciate the help and will study your example.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this part of the regex:

```
img|

<?php
$good="http://www.google.com/";
$bad="http://img.google.com/";
$r="#(?i)((?:f|ht)tps?://((?!jpe?g|gif|png|bmp))(?:([-a-z0-9()@:%_+.~\#?&;/=,])(?2))+(?!(?3)))#";
$rep="<a href=$1 target='_blank'><b>$1</b></a>"; 
echo preg_replace($r,$rep,$good); echo "\n";
echo preg_replace($r,$rep,$bad);
?>
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/uq6T8i)